# Building Go apps with private modules in Docker

Tags: docker, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build a go project in a docker container that relies on private submodules.

I was hoping that `--mount=type=ssh` would pass my ssh credentials to the container and it'd work. Currently I can build locally with just make the `GOPRIVATE` variable set and the `git config` update.

Here is my relevant `Dockerfile` currently

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM golang:1.14.3-alpine AS build
RUN apk add --no-cache git \
                openssh-client \
                ca-certificates

WORKDIR /src
ENV GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
ENV GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/company_foo"
RUN git config --global url."ssh://git@gitlab.com".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com"



# Authorize SSH Host
# Skip Host verification for git
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan gitlab.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts &&\
    chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts && touch /root/.ssh/config \
    && echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > /root/.ssh/config

COPY go.mod go.sum .
RUN --mount=type=ssh mkdir -p /var/ssh && \
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o \"ControlMaster auto\" -o \"ControlPersist 300\" -o \"ControlPath /var/ssh/%r@%h:%p\"" \
    go mod download
COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build go build -o api-server ./cmd/api-server
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build go build -o migrations ./cmd/migrations
```

I've also tried adding a `CI_JOB_TOKEN` with

```
RUN echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
```

but this also didn't work. Perhaps I did it wrong.

All of this results in the failure:

```
 revision v0.0.3: unknown revision v0.0.3
```

relating to one of our private repos.

Any advice would be appreciate.

I'm absolutely at a lost.

Comment: `--mount=type=ssh` should work. Do you have ssh-agent running and did you start the build with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh=default .`?

Answer (score 7):

This workes for me.

```
FROM golang:1.14
ARG USERNAME=user1
ARG PASSWORD=secret

WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
ENV GOPRIVATE=private.git.local/*
RUN echo "machine private.git.local login $USERNAME password $PASSWORD" > ~/.netrc

RUN go build -o testGo main.go
CMD ["/app/testGo"]
```

Answer (score 4):

pass your gitlab_token to docker file from gitlab_ci.yaml and do the following steps

```
RUN git config --global url."https://oauth2:$GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://git@gitlab.com/"
```

add your repo as GO_PRIVATE

```
ENV GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/*
```

copy .netrc file to docker root

```
COPY confidential/.netrc /root/.netrc
```

.netrc file will have the following structure

```
machine gitlab.com
login gitlab_user
password p@$$word
```

Comment: Good job, Paul. I only suggest you add some information to this answer, describing why each step is needed so that the answer can be useful for more people.