# Building Go apps with private gitlab modules in Docker

Tags: git, docker, go, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to build my go apps on a docker file. Inside my go.mod there is private package that needs authentication/ssh. This question is similar to [Building Go apps with private modules in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960934/building-go-apps-with-private-modules-in-docker), but in my case is i have to pull package from `gitlab` not from `github`. Here is my dockerfile:

```
# builder image
FROM golang:1.14.11-alpine AS builder

# specific directory for build process
WORKDIR /usr/src/build

# copying the source code 
# to the current working directory
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client
RUN apk add --no-cache git

# create ssh directory
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
RUN touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# allow private repo pull
RUN git config --global url."https://my-personal-access-token:token@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"

ADD . /go/src/gitlab.com/my-repo/backends/backend-structs
CMD cd /go/src/gitlab.com/my-repo/backends/backend-structs; go get /go/src/gitlab.com/my-repo/backends/backend-structs && go build -o /go/bin/backend-structs


# executing build process
RUN GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o app

# runtime image
FROM golang:1.14.11-alpine AS runtime

# create and use non-root user
# to increase container security 
# ref https://pythonspeed.com/articles/root-capabilities-docker-security/
RUN adduser myuser --disabled-password

USER myuser

WORKDIR /home/myuser

# copy the executable binary file from builder directory
# to the current working directory
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/build/app .

# exposing port
EXPOSE 8080

# run the application
CMD ["./app"]
```

i have tried to follow this tutorial https://divan.dev/posts/go_get_private/ , by changing `github.com` to `gitlab.com` still failed.

Here is the error details:

```
#17 5.830       remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
#17 5.830       fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/my-repo/backends.git/'
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o app]: exit code: 1
```

anyone here knows how to create dockerfile with golang private package(repo is hosted in gitlab.com) ?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the gitlab Go proxy? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/go_proxy/

Comment: i have read the documentation it says:

```
The Go proxy for GitLab is under development, and isn’t ready for production use due to potential performance issues with large repositories.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, do NOT use git configs to solve this. Only use `~/.netrc`. Here is a guide a made specifically for this: https://gist.github.com/MicahParks/1ba2b19c39d1e5fccc3e892837b10e21

I'll paste its contents below as well.

## Problem

The `go` command line tool needs to be able to fetch dependencies from your private GitLab, but authenticaiton is required.

This assumes your private GitLab is hosted at `privategitlab.company.com`.

## Environment variables

The following environment variables are recommended:

```sh
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com
```

The above lines might fit best in your shell startup, like a `~/.bashrc`.

#### Explanation

`GO111MODULE=on` tells Golang command line tools you are using modules. I have not tested this with projects not using
Golang modules on a private GitLab.

`GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com` tells Golang command line tools to not use public internet resources for the hostnames
listed (like the public module proxy).

## Get a personal access token from your private GitLab

To future proof these instructions, please follow [this guide from the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).
I know that the `read_api` scope is required for Golang command line tools to work, and I may suspect `read_repository` as
well, but have not confirmed this.

## Set up the `~/.netrc`

In order for the Golang command line tools to authenticate to GitLab, a `~/.netrc` file is best to use.

To create the file if it does not exist, run the following commands:

```sh
touch ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Now edit the contents of the file to match the following:

```
machine privategitlab.company.com login USERNAME_HERE password TOKEN_HERE
```

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is replaced with your GitLab username and `TOKEN_HERE` is replaced with the access token aquired in the
previous section.

## Common mistakes

Do **not** set up a global git configuration with something along the lines of this:

```sh
git config --global url."git@privategitlab.company.com:".insteadOf "https://privategitlab.company.com"
```

I beleive at the time of writing this, the SSH git is not fully supported by Golang command line tools and this may cause
conflicts with the `~/.netrc`.

## Bonus: SSH config file

For regular use of the `git` tool, not the Golang command line tools, it's convient to have a `~/.ssh/config` file set up.
In order to do this, run the following commands:

```sh
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Please note the permissions on the files and directory above are essentail for SSH to work in it's default configuration on
most Linux systems.

Then, edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to match the following:

```
Host privategitlab.company.com
  Hostname privategitlab.company.com
  User USERNAME_HERE
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Please note the spacing in the above file matters and will invalidate the file if it is incorrect.

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is your GitLab username and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the path to your SSH *private* key in your file system.
You've already uploaded its *public* key to GitLab. Here are [some instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

Answer (score 5):

I ran in that problem with private `github.com` repositories. I used the `ssh-agent` as a solution, however, I had difficulties because there are all sorts of assumptions in other answers. In my case, I had an issue with the filename for the key and the other issue was AppArmor.

I talk about my setup and these issues in details below.

### Experimental Docker Feature

First, in the `Dockerfile`, you want to allow newer options by adding a comment like so on the very first line:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
```

This will allow us to use the `--mount=type=ssh` option.

*Note: if the comment is not on the very first line, it will be ignored and the extensions such as the `--mount=...` fail.*

### Basic `Dockerfile` Setup

Like you, we use Go alpine. We also make sure to get `openssh-client`.

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
RUN apk --no-cache add build-base git mercurial gcc curl openssh-client
```

Detail, we add our code (entire folder):

```
ADD . .
```

### Create the `known_hosts` & `.gitconfig` Files

Now we have an issue because by default the key is not going to be recognized by SSH. To avoid the issue, we want to add the `github.com` (`gitlab.com`, in your case) key to our known hosts. We also want to make sure that `github.com` is used with SSH and not HTTPS.

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    echo -e "[url \"git@github.com:<company-name>\"]\n\tinsteadOf = https://github.com/<company-name>" >> ~/.gitconfig
```

> **Note:** *the `~` in a docker is always `/root` at this point.*

Some people attach a volume to give Docker access to their `known_hosts` file. I don't think that's safe and it is likely to break if you run online tools such as CircleCI.

### Build Go Application

This gives us all the necessary elements to finally build our application:

```
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOPRIVATE=github.com/<company-name>
RUN --mount=type=ssh cd cmd/app/ && go build -o app
```

*Our `Dockerfile` has a few more lines, not presented here, to define additional files and the final `ENTRYPOINT`.*

### Load Key in `ssh-agent`

We're nearly ready to run `docker build ...`. But we still need to define the key in our `ssh-agent`. This is very simple:

```
ssh-add id_rsa
```

> **SUPER VERY IMPORTANT:** The name of the key **MUST** be one of the defaults that `ssh` expects. `id_rsa` is one of them. If you have a key name other than one of the defaults, **it won't be picked up**.
>
> The following are the names checked in one of my tests. You see those when you run the `ssh -A -v ...` command (See below).
>
> ```
> #18 0.828 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
> #18 0.828 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
> #18 0.828 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
> #18 0.828 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
> #18 0.829 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
> ```

You can check that the key was loaded using:

```
ssh-add -l
```

The name of each key should appear at the end of the line. It has to be one of the defaults as mentioned above (you may also be able to fiddle around with a `Host` entry in the docker `.ssh/config` file).

### Build the Docker Image

To build the image, we now run `docker` like so:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --progress=plain .
```

*(you may, of course, use other options such as `--build-arg GO_VERSION=...` to force a version of golang)*

The `--progress=plain` gives you the ability to better see what is going on. Somehow, the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` prevents Docker from saving the intermediate images and containers so you would not be able to debug much without the option.

#### The `--ssh default` Option

This command line option may still be required. I actually use it. However, in the latest versions of docker, it automatically gets turn on if a `git@github.com` (or similar?) is detected. I'm not so sure that it can detect such in all situations. If you are having problems, make sure to include that option on your `... docker build ...` command line.

There is no need to specify any specifics in my experience. Just `default` is enough.

### Debugging the SSH Connection

If you have issues with the connection (i.e. SSH telling you that the connection was refused), then you can add a RUN command before the `RUN ... go build ...` to debug just that part:

```
RUN ssh -A -v -l git github.com
```

The `-A` option tells SSH to use the `ssh-agent` to retrieve the private key.
The `-v` asks SSH to print out debug information.
The `-l` option defines the user name. For `github.com`, you are expected to use `git` as the user name. By default, `ssh` uses `$USER` which inside a Docker would be `root`. That won't work.

If the connection works, `github.com` tells you that you were authorized but there is no shell to connect to so you get kicked out immediately. If you do not see that friendly message, then the SSH is not yet correctly setup. In fact, you can test that connection in your console like so:

```
$ ssh -l git github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi <your-name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

### Issue 1: `apparmor`

All of that did not work for me. The fact is that the `ssh-agent` creates a socket which is *hidden* under `/run/user/<uid>/keyring/ssh` and that path is not allowed to `docker ...` tools & services by default. At least, if your kernel has apparmor like Ubuntu servers do, it's not going to work.

You can see that this happens by looking at your `/var/log/syslog` or such similar file (could be `/var/log/auth.log`). There will be a DENIED error like so:

> Oct 28 10:42:13 ubuntu2004 kernel: [78018.511407] audit: type=1400 audit(1635442933.692:143): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.docker.docker" name="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh" pid=36260 comm="docker" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

We see the complete path to my keyring socket, the name of the apparmor profile that denied access, and the operation, which here is "connect". To fix the issue you first need to find the profile. This is under `/var/lib/snapd`:

```
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker
```

Then run this command:

```
$ sudo apparmor_parser -r \
          /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker
```

to refresh the apparmor settings.

If you don't use the snap version of Docker, profiles are generally found under `/etc/apparmor.d/...`, but I could not see the file in newer versions of docker (2021)...

Edit that file, go to the end, and just before the closing `}` character, enter this line:

```
/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh rw,
```

This means `docker` will be able to read and write to this specific socket.

Obviously, the `1000` is a specific user. Use your user ID (`id -u`) or the user identifier that is to run `docker build ...` if not you.

You may also allow all the users on that computer, but this is not recommended:

```
/run/user/[0-9]*/keyring/ssh rw,
```

*(It is still pretty safe since you only give that permission to `docker`, but you never know...)*

### Issue 2: Key Filename

I repeat the second issue here because that is very important. The key lookup from Docker is going to search for a key named `id_rsa` (and other similar default key names, see above). If you use a special name for your key, say `github_rsa`, then it won't be picked up by Docker.

You may be able to use the `.ssh/config` file for this purpose by adding:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/github_rsa
```

At some point, I fiddled with such but was not able to make it work. Probably because of Issue #1 (a.k.a. apparmor). If you are sharing your `Dockerfile` with many programmers, though, using a special name in this way needs to be well documented. Most programmers do not do such things and it could take them a while to find out why they can't create the Docker image on their system.

### Do Not `chmod` Anything!

On many pages/answers, you see that permissions are often resolved using the `chmod` command. For example, someone who thinks that their key is not accessible to Docker because of the permissions being 700 (rwx-----) on their `/run/user/1000` folder or 600 (rw-------) on their `~/.ssh/...` files may think that changing those permissions will help. It won't. The entry in the `ssh-agent` is enough to share your private key as required.

### Side Note About Using `.netrc`

As far as I can tell, when you use a `.netrc`, you include your credential in the Docker image. This means anyone who gets a copy of your image has your credentials. Probably not something you want. If your images are only used internally, it may be okay...