# SSH using old possibly cached user for connecting to GitHub

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-config

Mac OS (High Sierra) here. I have an SSH key, `example-gh-user`, and when I run `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/example-gh-user.pub` and paste it into an editor I see:

```
ssh-ed25519 <SOME_REALLY_LONG_ALPHANUM> me@example.org
```

Obviously for security reasons I am replacing the *actual* value of `<SOME_REALLY_LONG_ALPHANUM>` and `me@example.org` with the dummy values above. But everything looks ok.

On GitHub, I have a user, `example-gh-user`, that is using the `me@example.org` email, and I can log in with that user and see all my repos. Everything appears fine.

I have followed the [GitHub guide on adding an SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to my `example-gh-user` GitHub account. Hence, this SSH key should be associated with the same email address that my GH account is associated with.

In my `~/.ssh/config` file, I have the following entries:

```
Host example-dev
  Hostname   github2.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example-gh-user

Host github.com
  User git
  Hostname   github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example-gh-user
```

So far, so good, I think.

**However**, when I run the following from the command line:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

I get a huge dump of output that ends, interestingly-enough, with this:

```
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi my-old-gh-user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3452, received 2724 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 28403.1, received 22413.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Look at that! `my-old-gh-user`! That's an **old** GH user that I haven't used in *years*!

**Where is SSH and/or git/GitHub looking to grab that `my-old-gh-user` from?!** Does SSH *cache* old data some how? If I understand how everything works correctly, `~/.ssh/config` clearly directs SSH to use `~/.ssh/example-gh-user` when connecting as `git` user to `github.com`, right? Where am I going awry?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JimB (+1) I will try it. Sounds like you want me to try running `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/` from the repo root? Just curious what that would be doing under the hood?

Comment: You can see what it does "under the hood" in the linked answer, it adds an `insteadOf` entry into the git config. A full description of `insteadOf` can be found in the documentation, but it's basically; use ssh _instead of_ https.

Comment: OK I ran `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/` in the root directory of the repo and then tried `go build` but am getting the exact same error. Any idea what I can troubleshoot next?

Comment: Did you also set `GOPRIVATE` as described in the answer? Can you run the same commands with `git` directly within the same environment?

Comment: Yes, I set and exported `export GOPRIVATE=github.com/SomeExampleOrg` from inside my `~/.bash_profile`. Which git command(s) would you like me to try running myself?

Comment: Can you clone the repo with git?

Comment: Hmm. In that other question you linked, the only `git clone` command I see given as an example is `git clone git@github.com:secmask/awserver-go.git`. Would you like me to try `git clone git@github.com:SomeExampleOrg/some-app.git`?

Comment: You can verify the clone url from the github UI, but yes, that is the basic format.

Comment: OK very interesting, I created a `tmp` directory and tried cloning the repo to it using the command posted above...and it failed! So, if I've specified `git@github.com` as the user, and I'm specifying SSH, what does this tell you?

Comment: It tells me this has nothing to do with Go, and you need to fix your git+ssh configuration.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Try set set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`. Then clone again, and see if you see any clue in the SSH output.

Comment: Thanks @JimB (+1) I have edited my question to reflect this information and to place emphasis more on git/SSH misconfiguration rather than anything Go-related.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell what the current latest some-service/client version is, and how do I update go.mod to use it?

Simply `go get github.com/SomeExampleOrg/some-service/client` (assuming the original line is still in `go.mod`)

That will update `go.mod` to the latest for that repository, and the go.mod line about client will display the latest version available.

If that repository is a public one, Go will use the normal HTTPS URL, and your SSH configuration won't be needed.

---

TheOP mentions in the discussion

```sh
ssh -Tv git@github.com` generates the following output:

Hi my-old-gh-user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

> `my-old-gh-user` is an old GH user that I haven't used in years and must have configured SSH for.
>
> Where is SSH/GitHub grabbing the my-old-gh-user from?

By default, ssh will look for `~/.ssh/id_rsa`(`.pub`). If that old public kay was registered to the old GitHub user account SSH profile setting (as [documented by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)), that would explain why SSH identifies you by default with the old GitHub account.

Register a new public key in your new account, and make sure to replace the default one by your new key (or [use an `~/.ssh/config` file](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)), and SSH will aithenticate you kwith the new account.

> I generated `~/.ssh/example-gh-user`

Then you need to add to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```yaml
Host newgh
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example-gh-user
```

Then

```sh
ssh -Tv newgh

cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin newgh:<me>/<repo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer @VonC (+1) unfortauntely I had bolded a question (the one that you quoted in your answer) by mistake. I have edited my question to properly identify the _real_ question being asked here; if you have any thoughts I'd love to hear them! Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I understand, but did you try first to update the dependency as I suggested? Maybe that would have avoided the issue you got in the second part of your question.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup If not, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850333/6309

Comment: Thanks again @VonC (+1 for both). When I run `go get github.com/SomeExampleOrg/some-service/client` I get `go: github.com/SomeExampleOrg/some-service/client@v0.8.0: reading github.com/SomeExampleOrg/some-service/client/client/go.mod at revision client/v0.8.0: unknown revision client/v0.8.0`.

Comment: Looking at the link you posted above, I _believe_ the relevant information would be to set `GO111MODULE=on` and `GOPRIVATE=github.com/SomeExampleOrg` in my `~/.bash_profile`, which I have done, but the issue remains.

Comment: Trying the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` recommendation from above, when I go to clone the repo using SSH, I see `ERROR: Repository not found` in the verbose SSH output. Full output has been added above as an update to the original question.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup "Repository not found" means: 1/ either the repository name is not exactly the right one. 2/ Or you don't have the right to access it.

Comment: The repo name is correct, its clearly an issue with the SSH key. How to figure out what that issue is (I believe) the root/crux of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227713/discussion-between-vonc-and-hotmeatballsoup).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this interesting scenario would lie on the way ssh-agent works and caches the identities(SSH keys) on MacOS' Keychains.

You can do `ssh-add -L` to get all the currently loaded identities, wherein you should see the old git ssh user's identities.

You can flush the identities using `ssh-add -D` or `ssh-add -d` or reload the `ssh-agent` using:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
```